# How to make GET TYPE www.url.com/script?id=value?

Tags: php, apache, url

www.url.com/script?id=value. I want to get that kind of get type in PHP. How to do it? in .htaccess? How to do it? How to get it? If the file has no extension, how to get it?

Comment: you should be more specific about what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the resource at a particular URL can only be defined by the `Content-Type` header returned from the server.

If you wish to determine the type of a resource, then do a `HEAD` or a `GET` request, parse the response headers, and use the type returned.  [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is commonly used for this.

Comment: I don't understand well, sir.

Comment: @SpacezLyWang, What don't you understand?  Can you clarify?  I'm afraid we're having trouble understanding you as well.  Are you trying to get the type of a resource at a URL, or return a specific type from your script?

Comment: For faster understanding, is there any tutorials that explain it? @Brad

Comment: @SpacezLyWang, Yes, there are many.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/techniques-and-resources-for-mastering-curl/

Answer (score 0):

In theory you wouldn't need .htaccess to accomplish this. You could have a folder called "script", with an "index.php" that handles your data (`$_GET['id']`).

Comment: I've tried it. What you mean is www.url.com/script/?id=value But I want www.url.com/script?id=value